# Iterate ArrayList and pass index values to the volley and save the response at same Index

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Actually i am working on android application in which i have to calculate the current lat/lon of user and calculate the distance of nearBy Lat/Lon(already set in ArrayList) so for calculating the distance i am using the Distance api....
so all the above thing working well but the problem is

1. how can i iterate my List, and save the volley response at the same index.
2. The Second problem is, calculate distance function required parameters(fromLat,fromLon,toLat,toLon) and (FromLat,fromLon) is the current lat/lon, so when my activity is start it take the value of (FromLat,fromLon) is (0,0) because activity takes little bit time to get the Current Lat Lon of the user so How can I bypass this?

Java Code:

```
   //Iterate List and call the getDirection function
 for (ProviderItem item : workshopList) {
    toLat=item.getLat();
    toLon=item.getLon();

 getDirection(current_Lat,current_Lon,toLat,toLon);
 //now after that i have to set the volley response in item.setDirection();

 }


private void getDirection(fromLatitude, fromLongitude, toLatitude, toLongitude){

    String url = makeURL(fromLatitude, fromLongitude, toLatitude, toLongitude);


    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.d("Response",response);

        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray routeArray = json.getJSONArray("routes");
        JSONObject routes = routeArray.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONArray legsArray = routes.getJSONArray("legs");
        JSONObject legs = legsArray.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONObject distanceObj = legs.getJSONObject("distance");

        String parsedDistance=distanceObj.getString("text");

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

**NOTE:**

1. Should i have to write the Listener for getting the response from the volley function?
2. m getting the Current location in override onLocationChange function

Comment: pass the item in parameter and update it in the onResponse, for example

Comment: how can i access item.setDirection(); in onResponse

Comment: how about passing it as a parameter to the `getDirection` method?

Comment: i am not getting